# Make a document library the sites default homepage

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am making a very simple document library.  Sharepoint foundation 2010

I have a number of countrys sites, displayed as tabs at the top, each site contains 1 document library.

I would like to click the country site tab and then the document library opens.  I dont want users to have to click the document library quick link on the left, I intend on hiding this.

The only way I have got this working is to edit the site default page and add edit the page and then add the document library as a webpart.  However this causes other issues.

There must be a way the the site opens directly to a doc library page??  any options?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kev,

I hope 1 of the options given in this article should help you:
[SharePoint: How to change the default home page](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2011/06/sharepoint-how-to-change-default-home.html)

Powershell method looks promising for you, because you have SharePoint Foundation, below is taken from the link above:

Via PowerShell:
For SharePoint 2010:

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://yourserver/sites/yoursite
$web = $site.RootWeb
  (or $web = $site.OpenWeb("yoursubsite")
$folder = $web.RootFolder
$folder.WelcomePage = "SitePages/home.aspx"
  (or  $folder.WelcomePage = "default.aspx")
  (or  $folder.WelcomePage = "Shared%20Documents/mycustomwebpartpage.aspx")
$folder.update()
$web.Dispose()
$site.Dispose()
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks .. the first link pointed me in the right direction.   I opened the site in designer, found the relevant file for the document library in each site (allitems.aspx) then right clicked and 'set to homepage'

Comment: Good to know it helped !

Answer (score 2):

It may be too late to share this workaround. But i find a quick way to do it without turning on features or running powershell.
Go to **URL** `/_layouts/15/AreaWelcomePage.aspx` and change it. You need to put in **relative path** based on your site. This is actually the **Welcome Page feature** for **Publishing** but you can directly access to this page without turning on the feature.

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround is go to the **Document Library** default page (which is usually `/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx`).
Click **"Edit Page"** in the Site Action menu to change the Document Library page to Edit Mode.

And when it is in Edit Mode, the **Make Home Page button** will appear for you to set the default homepage.
[image]
Hope it helps

Comment: Your image link doesn't show any image

Comment: This seemed like the perfect solution, but I found that hitting _home_ took me back to the original welcome page

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Sharepoint StackExchange and yes this is possible.

What you need to have is publishing turned on which is a **standard feature**, this needs to be turned on as a feature for the site collection "**Publishing Infrastructure**" and at the site level "**Publishing**"

Once these are turned on under "**Site Actions > Site Settings > Look and Feel**" you will get a new option called "**Welcome page**". You paste the url you want as the sites landing page in here and hey presto it will become the default home page.

You can also now edit the Navigation and make things a little more user friendly.

Comment: Publishing feature is only available in SharePoint Server 2010 standard and enterprise, and not in foundation.

Comment: Hi Arsalan, I was aware of that, but I bolded standard feature in my text just in case.

Comment: Thanks Arsalan, yes I am only on foundation!  Shame, I prefer to use the out of the box features.  I will look at your alternatives...

Comment: Thanks hugh for the fast response, but not helpful seeing as I am using foundation.   Cheers anyway