# Set library view as welcome page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, site

On 'Site settings' -> 'Welcome page' when I enter

```
/My Site/Shared Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx
```

and click OK I get the following error:

```
You can not set the Welcome Page for this site to a URL in the "Forms" folder. Please pick a URL to a Page in the Pages library as the Welcome Page.
```

[Another](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/52615/make-a-document-library-the-sites-default-homepage) answer suggests using SharePoint Designer to do this but I don't find the 'set to homepage' option when opening the site and navigating to the 'All Documents' view. (Rightclick only gives me 'Edit File in Advanced mode' and 'Rename' or 'Rename' and 'Delete' and 'List Settings' when in the left pane).

Is there any way to do this without scripts/code in SharePoint 2013?

**Edit:**
My goal is that the 'Files' and 'Library' options are available immediatley without having the user to click on the library title first. In other words: It would be nice to open a library view when visiting the site's home page.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Create Site Page Example Home.aspx
 Site Contents > Open Site Pages > in Files Tab Click New Document > Select Webpart Page > Name: Home Layout: Full Page Vertical > Create

Step 2: Add a Webpart > Select the Document Library(**Your Library**) > Add > Stop Editing

Step 3: Settings > Site Settings > Welcome Page > Browse Your Home page Home.aspx > Ok

Comment: Thanks, but this gives me a view that is different from the one that I get when I click on the library tile (Files and Library options are not there). I'll update my question with this goal.

Comment: You can set the web part to use any existing view on the library, or tweak the view to show what you want.

Comment: @EricAlexander yes but there is still the difference compared to when I enter the view url in the address bar and hit enter. Users would still have to click the library title to get this "raw" view (e.g. with Files and Library options available).

Comment: Add script Editor webpart to the home page > add the below script
<script src="/sites/Test/SiteAssets/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ3").mouseup();
});
</script>

you need to add the reference for jquery-1.11.3.min.js

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy to do if you using sharepoint site template xml definition.

Just apply a template that contains:

```
<pnp:WebSettings RequestAccessEmail="" NoCrawl="false" WelcomePage="myurl" SiteLogo="" AlternateCSS="" MasterPageUrl="{masterpagecatalog}/seattle.master" CustomMasterPageUrl="{masterpagecatalog}/seattle.master" CommentsOnSitePagesDisabled="true" QuickLaunchEnabled="false"/>
```

Where [myurl] is the relative url of your library, for instance: **documents**